# Why can't my BJT common emitter trigger the pin interrupt of an MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, bjt, common-emitter

I'm trying to build a noise detector that gets triggered by pretty much all audible noises, provided that they are loud enough. The schematic design is as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWYHwM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At the out put, the oscilloscope reads the maximum reading of 3.3V (saturation or maybe it is called using some other term) , the maximum output possible when I clap my hand forcefully near the microphone. The MCU requires a 1.5 V input to consider logic HIGH. The above all happened when the entire circuit is on a breadboard and not in the MCU circuit, and as soon as I jacked the bjt circuit into the MCU circuit, the max voltage of the output (as seen on scilloscope) drops down to 1 volt, and the MCU simply doesn't get triggered, and I'm positive the MCU can be triggered properly because if I zap the interrupt pin with a  jumper cable attached to 3.3v source, the program will enter the interrupt handler.

This is quite confusing as I'm basically applying a circuit from a magazine that the author said would work.

My questions:

A. Why isn't a circuit capable of 3.3V output triggering the 1.5V requirement MCU? As I mentioned it probably has something to do with the voltage drop and I can only speculate it has something to do with the circuit not supplying enough current.

B. How do I do to solve this problem (not triggering)?

Comment: Your schematic appears to show a short circuit between the collector and emitter. I assume that's a mistake?

Comment: It is a very marginal design and he probably did not use a 2N3904  maybe a 2N5088 or equiv with hFE>500. You are better off using a buffered CMOS inverter with 1k gain ratio resistors with a diode to detect and RC fast attack slow decay.

Comment: @Felthry YEA DUH.

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Could you please recommend such a "buffered CMOS inverter "? There are simply so many to choose from...

Comment: all are buffered unless stated otherwise UB in suffix. You can use 60dB gain at 5V then Peak detect into. Schmitt Trigger gate

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a pull-down or pull-up resistor enabled in the MCU? Because I would not expect the voltage to change when you connect it to the MCU, assuming a high-Z input and the same power supply voltage. So if you have that enabled, **turn it off**.

Regardless, as others have said, this is a pretty marginal circuit- the bias method is dubious (beta-dependent). If your electret capsule has less sensitivity than the original tinkerer that won't help either.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, I have an internal pull down, and I have no idea how effective it is since I do not know what parameter/property to look for.  I will turn it off and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that the 1V *low* you are getting when the transistor switches is still what the microcontroller may consider as a *high*.

Therefore it only sees a logic high all the time, not really seeing any edges, and not triggering.

I guess you could just further increase the collector resistance so the voltage when the transistor is on goes lower.

It may have worked for the author, as these voltages are sort of in the gray area where the behavior isn't really defined; it may work on one device and not on another. I believe most CMOS logic (and some micros, YMMV) is specced to consider voltages below 0.8V as a zero. Anything above that and your 1.5V isn't really defined as of what logic level it should return; this is due to process variations and so on.

Comment: You are probably right. Nevertheless what about the "voltage drop" I observed? Does it matter at all?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you add to your circuit's analog OUTPUT a *trigger circuit* that

1. converts the analog signal at OUTPUT into a digital logic HIGH/LOW signal that is suitable for use as a trigger input signal at the microcontroller, and
2. lets you specify a "trigger" voltage \$V_{TRIGGER}\$ (i.e., voltage threshold) at OUTPUT that causes the trigger circuit's digital logic output to switch logic HIGH for \$V_{OUTPUT} > V_{TRIGGER}\$ and to logic LOW for \$V_{OUTPUT} < V_{TRIGGER}\$ (or vice versa, if negative logic is desired).

The trigger circuit should also provide hysteresis so that when \$V_{OUTPUT}\approx V_{TRIGGER}\$ the trigger circuit's digital logic output signal does not "oscillate" between logic HIGH and LOW.

I recommend you read these white papers:

- *[Comparator with Hysteresis Reference Design](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu020a/tidu020a.pdf)*, written by Art Kay and Timothy Claycomb, published by Texas Instruments (2014).
- [Curing Comparator Instability with Hysteresis](http://www.analog.com/media/en/analog-dialogue/volume-34/number-1/articles/curing-comparator-instability-with-hysteresis.pdf), written by Reza Moghimi, published in Analog Dialog (2000).

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I fully understand what you want to achieve. But I gather you want minor sounds to trigger interrupts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnBk3T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think the AC portion of the electret (I'm assuming it is one, given the arrangement) output voltage is low; on the order of tens of millivolts. You haven't provided a datasheet for the electret and I can't guess about its sensitivity. \$R_4\$ in the circuit shown will impact that sensitivity, because that's how electrets work. (You may also need to adjust \$R_1\$.)

I didn't create the above circuit idea. I remember someone on EESE proposing a circuit similar to it, though not for an electret and instead for a very different purpose. I've also not tested this in this application and haven't given it a lot of thought since you haven't provided detailed information about your microphone. So just be aware that I'm offering this more as a conceptual approach to try out.